What are "Prime" planets?
I'm travelling a lot trying to reach the galaxy center, and I came across several random planets with the word "Prime" in their name. What's the reason of that?
Do Prime planets have different elements? Like resources or sentinels.
Or is it a random word picked to complete the planet's name like a Roman number usually present?

Planet names are generated by one of multiple styles.
In this case, 4-9 letters plus one of ten additions:

Prime
Major
Minor
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
Delta
Omega
Sigma
Tau

None of these generation methods/names are of any significance at all. The different names/styles are solely meant to provide some variation in planet names.

Ok now I feel dumb, I thought that Minor and Major were dimension related, and Gamma for radiation environment... I probably never encountered any Omega, Sigma or Tau one.

Well, it COULD have been like that
